# How can you get the ClassName of the target of a Call Operation Action in Sparx Enterprise Architect in the Code Templates?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I've created a UserControl in Visual Studio C# and reverse engineered it into EA.  The result is two partial classes.

So now, I'm working on building Activity diagrams in EA to model what is already in the code so I can generate the code from the model.  Once I can re-generate the existing code from the model, I'll move forward adding additional features through the model.

I've created an activity diagram to model the constructor.  In the constructor, I've created a Call Operation Action to call a method of the other part of the partial class.  I've set the Classifier of the target of the Call Operation Action to the other partial Class.

Now it turns out the EA's out of the box code generation doesn't seem to handle C# partial classes too well so I'm trying to update the template to support them.  In order to do that, I need to get the classifier of the target.  My though is to verify that the fully qualified name of the target classifier is the same as the fully qualified name of the class currently in scope.  In order to do that, I need to get the classifier of the target.

I think it would be pretty easy to get the information using an addin, and that my end up being the way I go, but I'm just trying to figure out if there is a way to do it without an add in.

Here is the code in the main .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EIIWEAAddin
{
    public partial class EIIWAddinWindow : UserControl
    {
        public EIIWAddinWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the designer.cs file

```
namespace EIIWEAAddin
{
    partial class EIIWAddinWindow
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(68, 153);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 25);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Hello from the EIIWAddin";
            // 
            // EIIWAddinWindow
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(12F, 25F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Name = "EIIWAddinWindow";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(459, 371);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    }
}
```

Here is the activity diagram...
[image]

I'd provide the XMI for the package except it is too large and I don't see a way to upload a file here.

Here is the Code for the C# Call Action Template.

```
%PI=""%
$EQ = "="

$GUID = $parameter1
%if $GUID==""%
%endTemplate%

$sActionName = %EASL_GET("Property", $GUID, "Name")%

$context = %EASL_GET("Property", $GUID, "Context")%
$contextClassifier = %EASL_GET("Property", $context, "Classifier")%

$behavior = %EASL_GET("Property", $GUID, "Behavior")%
$arguments = %EASLList="CallArgument" @separator="," @owner=$GUID @collection="Arguments"%

$target =  %EASL_GET("Property", $GUID, "Pin", "Target")%

$sUMLType = %EASL_GET("Property", $GUID, "UMLType")%
$BehParent =  %EASL_GET("Property", $behavior, "Parent")%

$sBehName = %EASL_GET("Property", $behavior, "Name")%
%if $sBehName == ""%
/*Warning: $sActionName - Associated behavior not found within the package!!*/
%endTemplate%

%if $sUMLType=="uml:CallBehaviorAction" and $BehParent != "" and $BehParent != classGUID%
/*Warning: $sBehName - Invoking behaviors from other classes - Not Supported!!*/
%endTemplate%

%if $sUMLType=="uml:CallOperationAction" and $BehParent != "" and $BehParent != classGUID and $target==""%
/*Warning: $sBehName - Invoking operations from other classes requires a "target" pin to be configured!!*/
%endTemplate%

%if $target != "" and $BehParent != classGUID%
$partial = %classTag:"partial"%
%if $partial != "true"%
$sPropName = %EASL_GET("Property", $target, "Name")%
%else%
/* JJH: Action Call: Calling an operation on a partial class but not on the part currently in scope */\n
/* JJH: Action Call: className = %className% */\n
$sTargetClassifier = %EASL_GET("Property", $target, "Classifier")
%endIf%
%else%
$sPropName = %EASL_GET("Property", $context, "Name")%
%endIf%

$Result =  %EASL_GET("Property", $GUID, "Pin", "Result")%
$sResultName =  %EASL_GET("Property",$Result,"Name")%
%if $sResultName != ""%
$sResultName $EQ 
%endIf%

%if $sPropName != ""%
$sPropName.
%endIf%

$sBehName($arguments);
```

I'm really just working on this section near the end...

```
%if $target != "" and $BehParent != classGUID%
$partial = %classTag:"partial"%
%if $partial != "true"%
$sPropName = %EASL_GET("Property", $target, "Name")%
%else%
/* JJH: Action Call: Calling an operation on a partial class but not on the part currently in scope */\n
/* JJH: Action Call: className = %className% */\n
$sTargetClassifier = %EASL_GET("Property", $target, "Classifier")
%endIf%
%else%
$sPropName = %EASL_GET("Property", $context, "Name")%
%endIf%
```

So again, my question is, how can I get the classifier of the target of a Call Operation Action from the Code Template?